# Правильно ли я понимаю что такое поток?

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с понятием потока и GIL в python3. Скажите пожалуйста в каких пунктах я ошибаюсь и, если можно, посоветуйте что почитать.

1. когда интерпретатор python-а запускает программу, то выделяется отдельный процесс.
2. далее програмист средствами языка программирования может создать несколько потоков в этом процессе и загрузить их(потоки) вычислениями.
3. при этом не имеет значения количество ядер процессора - то есть ОС сама будет решать какие ядра использовать для вычислений.
4. вследствие этого невозможно простым способом предоставить первое ядро для вычисления **только** первого потока, а второе ядро для вычисления **только** второго потока.
5. после старта программы потоки могут иметь доступ к её переменным и менять их.
6. однако, это будет происходить последовательно потому что существует GIL.
7. GIL делит время исполнения на малые периоды(0.005сек.) и разрешает в каждый отдельный период быть активным только одному потоку, а остальные в это время неактивны. далее становится активным следующий поток, а остальные засыпают. и так далее...
8. если атомарная операция вычисления в потоке занимает времени меньше чем 0.005сек, то не имеет смысла делить вычисления на несколько потоков потому что в из-за большого количества переключений два потока выполнять задачу медленнее чем один поток.
9. верно и обратное: то есть если атомарная опреация занимает времени много больше чем 0.005сек, то вычисления в двух потоках выполнятся быстрее чем в одном.